Can Skewness Be Computed for Counts Derived from a Symmetric Dirichlet Distribution?
I have a scenario where I generate label proportions for a dataset across different nodes using a symmetric Dirichlet distribution. These proportions are then used to allocate a fixed total number of samples per label $(N_c $ among the nodes, resulting in label counts for each node $ l_c^{(k)}$.
Specifically:

Proportions: $ p_c^{(k)} \sim \text{Dir}(\alpha) $, where $ K $ is the number of nodes.
Counts: $ l_c^{(k)} = p_c^{(k)} \cdot N_c $, where $ N_c $ is the total number of samples for label c.

My goal is to compute the skewness of the realized label counts $l_c^{(k)} $ across nodes. However, I have the following questions:

Does computing skewness for these counts require the counts $ \{l_c^{(k)}\}_{k=1}^K $ to form a probability distribution (e.g., normalized such that the counts sum to 1)?
Is it valid to compute skewness directly on the observed counts $ \{l_c^{(1)}, l_c^{(2)}, \dots, l_c^{(K)}\} $ without normalization?
Which skewness estimator is appropriate in this case?

Could I see the observed counts as data  $ \{l_c^{(1)}, l_c^{(2)}, \dots, l_c^{(K)}\} $  and compute statistics like mean and standard deviation although the vector comes from a multivariate distribution.

What might "skewness" mean (even intuitively) for you with a multivariate distribution?

@Henry: If the counts are rather the same or the counts differ in magnitude . Is it possible then?

Can I see the counts as data and compute the skeweness like that?

By the aggregation property I can see each count as realisation  of a beta distribution with the same parameters for each component.  Does skewness then make more sense if counts in each component come from this non multivariate distribution

As a statistician I would not call that "skewness", though I think I see your point.  You seem to be talking about how the proportions differ from $\left(\frac 1K,\frac 1K,\ldots,\frac 1K\right)$.

@Henry:Thank you, but is it mathematically correct to see this counts as data for which you compute statistical values like mean and variance, which are involved in the skewness calculation or does this not make sense?

As an example, if you have $k$ labels and a sample size $n$, observing $X_i$ in label $i$ i.e. a proportion $p_i= \frac{X_i}{n}$ of samples for each $i$, one possible statistic of interest might be $\sum_i (p_i-\frac1k)^2$, though there are others.

If you are testing for significance so sensitive to sample size, then  $nk \sum_i (p_i-\frac1k)^2 =\sum_i (X_i-\frac nk )^2 / \frac nk$ has a distribution close to a $\chi^2_{k-1}$ distribution when the true Dirichlet parameters are $\left(\frac 1k,\frac 1k,\ldots,\frac 1k\right)$.
